# spyderでtensorflowを使用する際にエラーが出ます。

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow, cuda, spyder

resnet101を用いて、画像の4クラス分類をしたいのですが、環境構築がうまくいきません。
自分のPCではないのですがGPUに2080を搭載したPCではうまく実行できているのでプログラムの問題ではないはずです。

クラス分類のプログラムでtensorflowをanacondaのspyderで起動しようとすると、以下の1枚目の画像の画面で止まるか、2,3枚目の画像のようなエラーが出ます。どのような対策をすればいいでしょうか。
どなたか解決策がわかる方、アドバイスをいただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

画像
[image: 1枚目 Connecting to kernel]

[image: 2枚目 an error occured while starting to kernel①]

[image: an error occured while starting to kernel②]

PCスペック:
・CPU intel Core i7-10700
・メモリ 16GB -> 48GB(32GB追加)
・SSD 256GB -> 1TBを別で追加
・GPU NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti

環境
・Windows10
・python3.8
・tensorflow-gpu 2.4.0
・CUDA 11.4
・cuDNN 8.4.0
・NVIDIAドライバー 472.84
・anacondaのspyder 5.1.5で実行

#### 試したこと

たくさん試したので、覚えている限り。
・CUDA 11.0や11.7での実行
・anacondaのアンインストール、再インストール
・tensorflow-gpu 2.3.0(CUDA 10.1)で実行　-> kernelのエラーは出なくなったが、全ての画像を1つめのクラスに分類してしまう。あとめっちゃ重い。
・NVIDIAのGPUドライバーのバージョンを下げる。(現在472.84)
・spyder-kernels 2.1.3のインストール
・jupyter_client 5.3.4をインストール->6.1.12にアップデート
・pyzmqを22.3.0にアップデート
・ipykernel 6.9.1をインストール

ちなみに、GPUを認識しているか確かめるために、以下のコードを実行したところ

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

以下のような出力を得ました。

```
2022-06-19 15:55:56.086356: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll

2022-06-19 15:55:56.086356: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.624579: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This 
TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the 
following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-06-19 15:55:58.628109: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.648654: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found 
device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 48 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 566.30GiB/s
2022-06-19 15:55:58.648687: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.673972: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.674015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.685174: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.691414: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.699329: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.707119: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.708915: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.708980: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding 
visible gpu devices: 0

2022-06-19 15:55:56.086356: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.624579: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This 
TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the 
following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-06-19 15:55:58.628109: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.648654: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found 
device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 48 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 566.30GiB/s
2022-06-19 15:55:58.648687: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.673972: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.674015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.685174: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.691414: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.699329: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.707119: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.708915: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2022-06-19 15:55:58.708980: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding 
visible gpu devices: 0
2022-06-19 15:55:59.078777: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device 
interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2022-06-19 15:55:59.078810: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2022-06-19 15:55:59.078820: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2022-06-19 15:55:59.078952: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created 
TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 6582 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA 
GeForce RTX 3070 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2022-06-19 15:55:59.079545: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA 
devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
```

06/27 追記:
@kunif様、@merino様に提案していただいた方法を行ったのですが、残念ながらうまくいきませんでした。お二人共ありがとうございました。
・試したこと
①メモリ増設
GPU専用メモリを増やすことが可能ならばもしかしたらうまくいくかも?
②学習画像数削減
元々495枚の画像でImageDataGeneratorにより4倍拡張をしておりましたが、387枚まで減らし、拡張も最低限の2倍まで減らしてもエラーが出てしまいます。
カーネルエラーの様子がちょっとだけ変わったので一応画像を添付しておきます。

やはりタスクマネージャーを見ていると、CUDAを起動した瞬間にエラーが出るのでそこに問題があると思うのですが、どなたかわかる方がいらしたらぜひ教えてください。よろしくお願いします。
あと、専用GPUメモリを8GBから増やす方法もあるのでしょうか。

[image: カーネルエラーの様子がちょっとだけ変わりました]

Comment: 表示されているエラーメッセージ的に、こちらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[tensorflow: Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65907365/9014308) あるいはこちらかも。[How to ressolve the error: Not creating XLA devices- tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68973148/9014308)

Comment: 「クラス分類のプログラムでtensorflowをanacondaのspyderで起動しようとすると」spyder以外ではそのプログラムは動作するのでしょうか？また他のプログラムでGPUは使用できているのでしょうか？

Comment: @merino 様、ご質問ありがとうございます。 Jupyter Notebookで同じプログラムを実行したところ、学習が始まるところで「The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.」と出て、kernelが再起動してしまいました。また、ほかのプログラムについてですが、最後まで実行できるものと同じく失敗するものがありました。具体的に試したのはVGG16を用いて手書き文字を認識するプログラムは成功しcudaでGPUを認識しているようで、VGG16で天気の画像から天気を4クラス分類するというのは失敗しました。

Comment: @kunif  様、情報提供ありがとうございます。1つ目のサイトの回答の通り実行したら、"MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.66 GiB for an array with shape (4748, 224, 224, 3) and data type float32"というエラーが出ました。PCのスペックが足りないということなのでしょうか。

Comment: 手書き文字と天気の画像で比較するとファイルサイズの違いはありそうですね。一度に読み込むデータ数を調整してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: @yomo さん、エラーメッセージの内容だと、PCの空きメモリのサイズが足りなさそうですね。(GPUの方かもしれませんが8.00GiBあるらしいのでその場合はDisplay表示用との配分でしょうか) そのPCのメモリを増やすかメモリの大きなPCに切り替えて実行させてみるか、merino さんのコメントのようにデータ数を調節してみると変わるかもしれませんね。あるいはanaconda/spyder等の同時に起動しているプログラムを減らしてpythonインタプリタ環境単独で動作させてみるとか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決?とまでは言いませんが、学習プログラム自体は動きました。
何が問題だったかはいまだにわかりませんが、とりあえず結果的に動くようになった経緯を記しておきます。

・cuDNNの中身がCUDAのフォルダに入っていなかった。(これはエラーの原因としてはかなり大きかったと思うのですが、これを直してもエラーが出続けたので別にも原因があります)
->ダウンロードしたcuDNNファイルをCUDAのフォルダで解凍。
・CUDA 11.7にさらに変更。GPUドライバとの互換性を考えて、11.7にしました。
・Visual Studio 2022ビルドツールのダウンロード、「C++ によるデスクトップ開発 」と「v143 ビルドツール用 C++/CLI サポート（最新）」をインストール。
(CUDA 11.7はVS2022でないとダメらしい)
・ZLIB DLL のダウンロードとインストール
コマンドプロンプトを管理者として実行してコマンドからインストール
・tensorflow-gpu 2.9.0のインストール(CUDA 11.7が最新なので、こちらも最新に合わせた)
・batch_sizeを縮小。
私のデータ数ではbatch_size=16でもスペック的に足りないようなことをエラーで言われたので、batch_size=4で実行したらうまくいきました。(batch_size=8も試してみます)

参考: https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/win/tensorflow2.html

学習時間がいつもより長いことと、タスクマネージャーを確認したらGPUメモリの「cuda」項目がなく、「3D」の項目が100%近くまで使われていることに違和感を覚えていますが、とりあえず動いたので、解決とさせていただきます。

皆様ありがとうございました。